# Flicker of Mouse in TextBox , Graph while Processing Large Data in other UI Control

Tags: c#, multithreading

My Application processes large data Entries and display each group of entries in Tree List View.
The Main Form has other Controls such as Text Box "Used as Filter for Entries" and Graph "Displays Entries Data"

Every thing work Great , The Problem is while Processing Data entries and Displaying on TreeListView if i places the Mouse on textbox or graph , it keeps flickering and blinking ! , i can write data successfully to textbox but it is always flickering.

Take into consideration that The function of handling that large data entries and display on TreeListView is in separate thread.

so what is the problem here ? and how this separate thread affects rest of other controls in my mainform ?

Comment: If using winforms, you can try setting DoubleBuffered property of the control to true

Comment: I used  this.SetStyle(
            ControlStyles.UserPaint |
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
            ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);  for MainForm and the affected Controls , nothing changed still

Answer (score 0):

- One solution: Make everything `Visible = false` until your processing finish up, then `Visible = true`. You can also display a message "Please wait" while the items are hidden.
- Another solution: avoid on-ui-thread long operations. Avoid fast add/delete into listview or treeview. It is better to `clear` everything then add everything. Yo can also hide your treeview, add items to it, then show it.

Comment: But I want Data to be contentiously displayed while i can write any thing at textbox.  My main question is why textbox is effected Data Processing since it is in separate thread ?

Comment: It is not in a separate thread. All UI-controls are on "main ui thread". Any processing within the UI Thread causes everything to hung/flicker.